# How can I get Request object inside a class in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, request

I have a class in Symfony that implements an interface. I need to have $request to have POST params. This is my function:

```
class WebserviceUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $salt = "";
        $roles = "";
        // make a call to your webservice here

        .....
    }
...
}
```

I can't do this:

```
public function loadUserByUsername($username, Request $request)
```

because i need to implement the interface, and i get this error:

> FatalErrorException: Compile Error: Declaration of
>   Actas\Gestion\UserBundle\Security\User\WebserviceUserProvider::loadUserByUsername()
>   must be compatible with
>   Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface::loadUserByUsername($username)

How can i get the request params? This class is called from login, and i need the password sent by it to use a WebService to authenticate the user.

Thank you very much in advance!

This is my services.xml in the Bundle:

```
# src/Actas/Gestion/UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
parameters:
    webservice_user_provider.class: Actas\Gestion\UserBundle\Security\User\WebserviceUserProvider

services:
    webservice_user_provider:
        class: "%webservice_user_provider.class%"
        scope: container
        calls:
                - [setServiceContainer , ["@service_container"]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to Czechnology's answer, you could also inject the request using a setter method.  In services.yml add:

```
my_service:
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\Service\WebserviceUserProvider
    scope: request
    calls:
        - [setRequest , ["@request"]]
```

Then declare your class like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class WebserviceUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface {
    private $request;
    public function setRequest( Request $request ) {

        $this->request = $request;
    }
    // ...
}
```

If you have scope widening issues, you could also try injecting the service container and getting the requesting from it.  In services declare your service like this:

```
my_service:
class: Acme\DemoBundle\Service\WebserviceUserProvider
calls:
    - [setRequest , ["@service_container"]]
```

Now just use the container to get the request:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class WebserviceUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface {
    private $request;
    public function setRequest( ContainerInterface $container ) {

        $this->request = $container->get('request');
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ScopeWideningInjectionException] Scope Widening Injection detected: The definition "webservice_user_provider" references the service "request" which belongs to a narrower scope. Generally, it is safer to either move "webservice_user_provider" to scope "request" or alternatively rely on the provider pattern by injecting the container itself, and requesting the service "request" each time it is needed. In rare, special cases however that might not be necessary, then you can set the reference to strict=false to get rid of this error.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm getting this error now. I don't know if i should write my responses in another place! (i'm new here)

Comment: Are you including the scope: request line in your service declaration?

Comment: You could try passing the service container @service_container then calling $container->get('request') using the same dependency injection principles.

Comment: Solved! I've get the container as you indicate and all works fine now. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I prefer not to inject the whole container but it's sometimes hard with the scope. Didn't know about the `calls` directive though, thanks! +1

Answer (score 6):

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class NewService
{

    protected $request;

    public function setRequest(RequestStack $request_stack)
    {
        $this->request = $request_stack->getCurrentRequest();
    }

}
```

In Config file

```
services:

    new.service:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\NewService
        calls:
            - [setRequest, [@request_stack]]
```

Reference : 
http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack

Answer (score 2):

How do you load the service? You can inject various stuff in the service:

```
my_service:
    class:      Acme\DemoBundle\Service\WebserviceUserProvider
    arguments:  [@request]
    scope:      request
```

and use it in the constructor

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class WebserviceUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface {
    private $request;
    public function __construct(Request $request) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I get this error:  
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ScopeWideningInjectionException] Scope Widening Injection detected: The definition "security.context_listener" references the service webservice_user_provider" which belongs to a narrower scope. Generally, it is safer to either move "security.context_listener" to scope "request" or alternatively rely on the provider pattern by injecting the container itself, and requesting the service "webservice_user_provider" each time it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. May be it helps this solution. You can inject the @service_container to the service. Then you can check if the scope 'request' is active and get then the request. This is a service for creating a global variable for accesing the language variables from twig.

```
/**
* Servicio para acceder a los datos del idioma actual de forma global.
*
* @author jaime
*
*/
class IdiomaService {

    private $idioma;

    /**
     * Constructor de la clase.
     */
    public function __construct(Container $container, EntityManager $manager, SecurityContext $context){ //, $request ) {
        if ($container->isScopeActive('request')) {
            $_locale = $container->get('request')->getLocale();
        }else{
            $_locale = 'es';
        }
        $this->idioma = $manager->getRepository ( 'BackBundle:Idioma' )->findOneByCodigo ( $_locale);
    }

    public function getIdioma() {
        return $this->idioma;
    }
}
```